# Range aggregation on date_range field

Tags: elasticsearch, date-range

I have a set of documents with date range. I want to get schedule with in specific duration.

For example, following are 2 events.

```
1. Event 1 - from 10th to 20th
2. Event 2 - from 15th to 25th
```

Get schedule from 1st to 30th. Expecting following output.

```
1. Date 10th to 14th - Event 1
2. Date 15th to 20th - Event 1 and Event 2
3. Date 21st to 25th - Event 2
```

Please suggest how can i achieve this.

Comment: Could you explain better the fields and the queries used? Without the fields mapping is difficult to create a specific query.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [range datatypes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/range.html) to support this. See this [introduction blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/numeric-and-date-ranges-in-elasticsearch-just-another-brick-in-the-wall)